# Simple Slideshow of Webpages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace an existing webpage with another one without opening up another webpage.

Slide1 opens without any issue, but I am getting this error when executing this web page code, as slide2 is selected.  No issue with the code if selecting actual webpages such as google and yahoo, but it is having this issue when grabbing html slides from a server drive.

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"
>
> IE.navigate2 "\FMC9050101\Proj\6513_OAK3\Jobads\slide2.htm"

Hoping someone could help with this code issue.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't JavaScript related, but the error is saying that IE doesn't have a variable `navigate2`.  Is your IE null? Do a simple check `If IE is Nothing Then`.

Comment: How do you open the slideshow? Can you show us the code?

Comment: It does appear that IE is "Nothing" when it comes back from a Function that looks for a the webpage.

Comment: This is the code that starts the slideshow

Comment: Sub TestGetIE()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "\\FMC9050101\Proj\6513_OAK3\Jobads\slide1.htm"
WaitFor IE
Set IE = GetIE("\\FMC9050101\Proj\6513_OAK3\Jobads\slide1.htm")

Do While x < 99999 ' ideally this is endless
For i = 2 To 4
If IE Is Nothing Then MsgBox "IE is Nothing"
IE.navigate "\\FMC9050101\Proj\6513_OAK3\Jobads\slide" & i & ".htm"
x = x + 1
Next
Loop

End Sub

Comment: This Function, looks for the webpage that it was on and is expected to keep that webpage for the next slide.

Comment: Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object
Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim retVal As Object
Set retVal = Nothing
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each o In objShellWindows
sURL = ""
'check the URL and if it's the one you want then
' assign it to the return value
sURL = o.LocationURL
If sURL Like sLocation & "*" Then
Set retVal = o
Exit For
End If
Next o
Set GetIE = retVal
End Function

Comment: It looks like the function works with regular webpages, but is having an issue with dealing with the added "file://" added as the prefix to the address?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.